# GWT test case fail to run: JUnitFatalLaunchException

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit, gwt-rpc

I am trying to run GWT test from eclipse 3.6 but have stuck with this strange error.

The test class 'com.company.demo.smartgwt.RequestBuilderTest' was not found in module 'com.company.demo.smartgwt.module'; no compilation unit for that type was seen

Have tried adding source folder into Run Dialog--> classpath and source tabs as mentioned [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/testing-gwt-applications). No luck yet and running out of options.. Any suggestions folks?

Full error stack:

```
com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitFatalLaunchException: The test class 'com.company.demo.smartgwt.RequestBuilderTest' was not found in module 'com.company.demo.smartgwt.module'; no compilation unit for that type was seen
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.checkTestClassInCurrentModule(JUnitShell.java:718)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1317)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1280)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:625)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:456)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.run(GWTTestCase.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Some interesting hints can be found at http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/testing_gwt_applications also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GWT test was not in the same package as the class under test.. moving it into the same package resolved this issue. Strange though

Comment: The GWT tests are too slow to run, you can try your hands on using Junit and Mockito to speed up the tests of interaction between widgets

Comment: A useful link on GWT unit testing http://blog.hivedevelopment.co.uk/2009/10/introduction-to-mvp-unit-testing-part.html

Answer (score 16):

The issue is probably that you have run the test as a JUnitTest rather than a GWT Junit Testcase.

In Eclipse, delete your run configuration for the test, right click the class, press "Run As" and select "GWT Test Case".

Worked for me.

I will agree with other answers that GWT test are too slow - but unfortunatrely , you may need them occassionally.

Comment: If the "GWT Test Case" doesn't happen to show up, ensure that the project has "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox checked in "Project Properties->Google->Web Toolkit".

Answer (score 2):

Look at your GWTTestCase.getModuleName() method and make sure it's returning the right module.